# Plot or Integrate one vector of data points vs another vector

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have two column vectors y and x full of data points, they are of the same size. Is it possible to plot the column vector y against the column vector x?
Is it possible to integrate y against x?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have the following data (sampled Sine function):

```
n = 30;
x = Table[t, {t, 0, 4 π, π/10}];
y = N[Sin[x]];
```

`y` against `x` can be plotted with `ListPlot` and `Transpose` can be used to create a list of `{xi, yi}` coordinates

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{x, y}], Joined -> True, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

The integration depends of the above data can be done - for example - with the trapezoidal rule. Assuming {x1, y1} and {x2, y2} are two successive points, the area of the trapezoid is:

```
TrapezoidArea[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}] := (y1 + y2)/2/(x2 - x1)
```

All we need is to create point pairs with `Partition`, `Map` (`/@`) the above function and use `Total` to get the result:

```
pointPairs = Partition[Transpose[{x, y}], 2, 1];
Total[TrapezoidArea /@ pointPairs]
```

As you can imagine, the result will be `0`.

Of course, the above can be done in a single function:

```
TrapezoidalIntegrate[x_List, y_List] := 
(#[[1, 2]] + #[[2, 2]])/2/(#[[2, 1]] - #[[1, 1]])& /@ 
   Partition[Transpose[{x, y}], 2, 1] // Total
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 data = MapThread[List,{Data,xData}]
 line = Fit[data, {1, x}, x]
```